# ¿Cómo construir una uri de redireccionamiento de OAuth para dispositivos Android, remplazando localhost?

Tags: java, android-studio, youtube-api, google-oauth

al terminar de autenticarme como usuario usando OAuth de YoutubeDataApiv3 se abre la URI de redireccionamiento que devuelve el código de autorización / o no autorización por lo que tengo entendido. Dicha URI me rechaza la conexión debido a que tengo construida la URI usando localhost y por lo que me han explicado localhost solo se utiliza para ordenadores, Ahora yo estoy utilizando un dispositivo móvil Android para hacer la petición de suscripción a YoutubeDataApiv3,por lo que la URI de redireccionamiento después del proceso de autenticación será diferente al de ordenador, Pero... ¿Cuál es la forma correcta de escribir una URI de redireccionamiento para dispositivos Android?

mi actual URI de redireccionamiento = http://localhost:8080/Callback?code=4%2F0AY0e-g59uUkDc4tux6RIlUzYadU0nKuLHYp8kvX3sFbPe9N8ZKsjuB3lbK4JqPKZVSRNfQ&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fyoutube

^
|
esa URI de redireccionamiento es construida por `LocalServerReceiver.getRedirectUri()`

LocalServerreceiver.getRedirectUri()

```
 @Override
public String getRedirectUri() throws IOException {
    if (port == -1) {
        port = getUnusedPort();
    }
    server = new Server(port);
    for (Connector c : server.getConnectors()) {
        c.setHost(host);
    }
    server.addHandler(new CallbackHandler());
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                server.start();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Throwables.propagateIfPossible(e);
                try {
                    throw new IOException(e);

                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    });

    return "http://" + host + ":" + port + CALLBACK_PATH;
}
```

este metodo es invocado por `AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp.authorize()` cuando se va abrir en el navegador.

AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp.authorize() :

```
public Credential authorize(String userId) throws IOException {
    try {
        Credential credential = flow.loadCredential(userId);
        if (credential != null
                && (credential.getRefreshToken() != null
                || credential.getExpiresInSeconds() == null
                || credential.getExpiresInSeconds() > 60)) {
            return credential;
        }
        // open in browser
        String redirectUri = receiver.getRedirectUri();
        System.out.println("redirectUri = " + redirectUri);
        AuthorizationCodeRequestUrl authorizationUrl =
                flow.newAuthorizationUrl().setRedirectUri(redirectUri);
        onAuthorization(authorizationUrl,activity_parent);
        // receive authorization code and exchange it for an access token
        String code = receiver.waitForCode();
        TokenResponse response = flow.newTokenRequest(code).setRedirectUri(redirectUri).execute();
        // store credential and return it
        return flow.createAndStoreCredential(response, userId);
    } finally {
        receiver.stop();
    }
}
```

.En conclusión necesito saber como construir una URI de redireccionamiento que se adapte con dispositivos Android, para evitar rechazos de conexión.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Localhost se denomina a un servidor que esta operando en tu misma maquina. Un celular no tiene localhost, asi que se va a comunicar a un servidor. Cual es el error que recibis por el cual falla la autenticacion?

Comment: Hola @gbianchi , muchas gracias por las sugerencias soy bastante nuevo en esta plataforma  :)). ahorita modifico la pregunta y la generalizo un poco mas

Comment: @gbianchi ya he editado la pregunta, seria estupendo que me ayudaras a solucionarlo, Espero y me de a entender, Gracias de antemano :)))).

Comment: Yo no se absolutamente nada de java para android. Algun experto podra atudarte con tu problema.

Comment: @gbianchi vale gracias de todos modos, esperare entonces.